# how can I pass more than 8 arugements to ibm_db bind_param?

Tags: python, db2

I am trying to `Upsert` to db2 z/os. This is short replica of my query statement

```
-- sql
MERGE INTO SampleSchema.? as T
USING (VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)) S(A, B, C, D, E)
on T.A = S.A 
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE SET
   T.B = ?,
   T.C = ?,
   T.D = ?
   T.E = ?
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
   INSERT (T.A, T.B, T.C, T.D, T.E)
   VALUES (S.A, S.B, S.C, S.D, S.E)
```

My python code is,

```py
import pandas as pd
'''
df looks like,
         A   B   C   D   E
1       a1   b1  c1  d1  e1
2       a2   b2  c2  d2  e2
.....
100000  a10000 ... ... ... ....
'''

import ibm_db

conn = ibm_db.connect("database", "username", "password")
stmt = ibm_db.prepare(conn, sql) # sql is from the above sql statement
table = "sampleTable"
for _, row in df.iterrows():
    ibm_db.bind_param(stmt, table, row["A"], row["B"], row["C"], row["D"], row["E"], row["B"], row["C"], row["D"], row["E"])
ibm_db.execute(stmt)
```

However, I get this error

```
TypeError: function takes at most 8 arguments (11 given)
```

How can I pass more than 8 arguments? or is it possible to pass dictionary type?(it has many repeated variable that I think I can reduce a number of variables)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Consider using the pandas `to_sql` method .

Comment: @mao I cannot use `to_sql`. I tried it at first shot, but there is an issue between db2 z/os and `to_sql`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error suggests to check what parameters are expected. Let's take a look at the function definition for [ibm_db.bind_param](https://github.com/ibmdb/python-ibmdb/wiki/APIs#ibm_dbbind_param):

```
bool ibm_db.bind_param (IBM_DBStatement stmt, int parameter-number, string variable
 [, int parameter-type [, int data-type [, int precision [, int scale [, int size]]]]] )
```

**bind_param** is intended to bind a value to a single parameter, identified by the **parameter-number**. If you have more parameters, you need to call **bind_param** multiple times. Here is such an example from the linked docs:

```
sql_stmt = "insert into tabmany values(?,?)"
stmt = ibm_db.prepare(conn, sql_stmt)
id = 3
name = "Sam"
ibm_db.bind_param(stmt, 1, id)
ibm_db.bind_param(stmt, 2, name)
```

Comment: What if sql_stmt has more than 8 values needs ? like `sql_stmt = "insert into tabmany values (?, ?, ?, ?, ? ,? ,?, ?, ?)"` that you need to pass 9 arguments in `bind_param`.

Comment: Read what I wrote. You would need to have 9 calls to bind_param(). And in each have a different parameter-number, e.g., 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9.

Comment: In my answer, see the example with two (2) parameters. There are two (2) calls to bind_param, each for a different parameter.

Comment: so you are saying that calling bind_param separately, right? For example, my case I need to iterate pandas dataframe and I have 11 placeholder(`?`), then it would be like `for _, row df.iterrows(): ibm_db.bind_param(stmt, row[[0], row[1]) ibm_db.bind_param(stmt, row[2]. row[3])` .Did I get your point?

Comment: yes, but use a loop variable in the "for"

Comment: I am now getting this error, `Describe Param Failed: [IBM][CLI Driver][DB2] SQL0104N  An unexpected token "?" was found following "?".  Expected tokens may include:  "<IDENTIFIER>".  SQLSTATE=42601
 SQLCODE=-104`  I went through the doc you posted and followed them

Comment: In your SQL you have to explicitly name the table, you cannot use a parameter. That is a different problem.